# Getting NPE in custom OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I'm trying to implement custom OnClickListner, but my app is crashing when I'm defining it.

```
public class OCL_Test implements View.OnClickListener
{
    MyActivity mActivity;

    public OCL_Test(MyActivity act)
    {
        this.mActivity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //all stuff here
    }
} <- LINE #247 IS HERE
```

In MyActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle s)
{
    super.onCreate(s);

    Initialize();
}

public void Initialize()
{
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSPUtils = new SPUtils(this);
    if (mSPUtils.useAlternativeLayout())
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alt);
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_norm);
    }
    //Layouts are inflating OK

    //stuff here

    mListener = new OCL_Test(MyActivity.this);

    //stuff here
}
```

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.app/ru.app.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at ru.app.OCL_Test$100000000.<init>(OCL_Test.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at ru.app.OCL_Test.<init>(OCL_Test.java:247)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at ru.app.MyActivity.Initialize(MyActivity.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at ru.app.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
E/AndroidRuntime(3363):     ... 11 more
```

In log you can see reference to line #247, but there's only "}", because that bracket is closing class. How I can fix that error?

**Update** I figured out my problem. I didn't know about I can't create any View.OnClickListeners in class implements View.OnClickListener.

There were two more OnClickListener inside my class:

```
View.OnClickListener q_Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {...};
View.OnClickListener l_Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {...};
```

And some buttons using these listeners:

```
mButton1.setOnClickListener(q_Listener); //I've replaced "*_Listener" with
mButton2.setOnClickListener(l_Listener); ///"this", removed old listeners...
```

..And my app not crashing anymore! Thanks for your help <strike>and disliking my question</strike>

Comment: We can't see the line numbers in the code that you posted, so I'm not sure what is on line 247.

Comment: But there's only "}" on line #247

Comment: When that happens, it usually means that the problem is occurring on the line just before that or on the line that is instantiating the class.

Comment: I've edited my question. Before line 247 there's onClick method. But I'm not calling it, I'm trying to define listener.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your OCL_Test class as you've posted it. Sorry.

Comment: Did you declare `mSPUtils` somewhere? In the code you posted we only see it being initialized so from what I see that is the best candidate. Same goes for `mListener` only being initialized but not declared.

Comment: Could you please show your OCL_Test code that is inside onClick() method?

Comment: @ImmortalDev and joao2fast4u, Problem is solved now.